# form gets submitted before jquery dialog ui

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

i have this openid plugin but when i click on aol the dialog opens and within no time it automatically gets closed and the form is submitted. i want that it shud stop at time when dialog opens and form shud be submitted only when i close the dialog box

please help me out

```
(function($){
  $.fn.openid = function() {
    $('input').click(function(e){
      var provider = $(this).attr('class');
     if (provider == 'aol') {
        $("#dialog").dialog();  
         }
     else{
      var provider_url = $(this).attr('id');  //get id
      var myinput = $('<input type="hidden" name="provider_url"/>').val(provider_url);
        }  
        $('form').append(myinput);
      $('form').submit();
    })
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't make sense. If the provider is aol, open a dialog, otherwise get the provider from the ID. The, regardless of the if/else, submit the form. Shouldn't you spawn the dialog regardless of provider and then if you want it submitted on the dialog close, move that submit code within the close event of the dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Add `e.stopPropogation();` to the first line of the `click` event handler to prevent the normal form submission from occurring.